# GitHub - Merge Pull Request (with Squash Commits) - branch still says 7 commits ahead of master?

Tags: git, github

On my own repository, I have set `master` branch as `protected` in `Settings>Branches` so that my own `Pull Requests` won't be auto accepted. This allows me to then choose the option to `Squash Commits` when accepting my own `Pull Request`.

The problem is that after this merge, if I go go `Branches` on GitHub, the merged branch still shows **7 commits ahead of master**. How can I get update this?

**Update**

I don't think there is a way around this. I am going to use `Squash & Merge`, delete the `branch`, and create a `tag` on `master` with the name of the merged branch

Comment: Your title states that the branch is 5 commits ahead, but your question claims 7.  Regardless, most likely a feature branch would be ahead of `master`, so what is the problem?

Comment: Well, is your feature branch logically ahead or behind `master`?  Nothing I have seen so far indicates a problem yet.

Comment: Yeah, that is strange, although mostly a moot point because you won't be using that feature branch after merging most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Merge with squash is not tracked by git, so the branch is still shown as unmerged. You should somehow remember which branches are merged. As far as I understand, the idea is that you remove the branches as soon as you merge them.

Comment: My personal opinion is that you should use just regular merge, without squash. Then it would behave as you expect.